# How to prevent uibutton alpha from going to zero when button tapped in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

The alpha of a UIbutton goes to zero, and it becomes transparent when tapped. Ive added this IBAction

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.highlighted = false
    //...
}
```

and the UIButton still gets transparent when touched. How to prevent that?

Comment: Is your button displaying an image instead of text?

Comment: yes a background image for default and selected states

Comment: Then you probably don't have an image for the highlighted state.

Comment: The highlighted background image is set actually

Comment: I just tested in simulator with btn image and it does not disappear when tapped, check all your ibactions which is assigned with that button and check any other function like uiviewcontroller methods or something.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I wrestled with this problem and finally fixed it by changing the button type from System to Custom.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like:

```
yourButtonClass.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
```